# How to count events in groups before a specific event

Tags: sql, postgresql, string-function

Suppose I have a table like the following:

```
\d events 
    Table "public.events
   Column   |           Type           | Modifiers 
------------+--------------------------+-----------
 my_id      | bigint                   | 
 tstamp     | timestamp with time zone | 
 event_type | text                     |
```

With example data:

```
   my_id     |           tstamp           | event_type 
------------+----------------------------+------------
 1111111111 | 2015-11-14 09:02:46.185+02 | A
 1111111111 | 2015-11-14 17:32:58+02     | B
 1111111111 | 2015-11-28 15:06:30.895+02 | A
 1111111111 | 2015-12-05 15:22:31.582+02 | A
 2222222222 | 2015-11-17 15:06:07.481+02 | A
 2222222222 | 2015-11-17 20:30:03+02     | B
 2222222222 | 2015-12-04 15:36:31.532+02 | A
 3333333333 | 2015-11-20 15:06:01.621+02 | A
 3333333333 | 2015-11-20 19:15:09.908+02 | A
 3333333333 | 2015-11-21 15:06:01.621+02 | A
 3333333333 | 2015-11-26 09:07:45.134+02 | B
 3333333333 | 2015-11-27 14:39:31.657+02 | A
 4444444444 | 2015-12-05 10:21:21.441+02 | A
 4444444444 | 2015-12-05 20:00:40.772+02 | B
```

I would like to count all events A per my_id before event B.

The expected output would be:

```
   my_id   | events_before_B 
-----------+-----------------
1111111111 | 1
2222222222 | 2
3333333333 | 3
4444444444 | 1
```

Postgres version 9.4

Comment: Can you also add example data where no B at all, B first, and only B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT my_id
      ,position('B' IN string_agg(event_type, '')) - 1 events_before_B
FROM events
GROUP BY my_id
ORDER BY my_id
```

[`SQLFIDDLE-DEMO`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4408a/1)

---

Explanation:

[`string_agg()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-aggregate.html)

`select my_id,string_agg(event_type,'') from events group by my_id` yields

```
my_id      string_agg 
---------- ---------- 
1111111111 ABAA       
2222222222 ABA        
3333333333 AAABA      
4444444444 AB
```

---

[`position()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-string.html)

`select position('B' in 'AAABAA')` can be used to find out the position of `B` in string `AAABAA`

```
position 
-------- 
4
```

So `select position('B' in 'AAABAA')-1` yields the position of `A` just before `B`

```
position 
-------- 
3
```

Comment: Thnx. I used your solution. I just added an `order by` tstamp since events needs to be ordered.
`SELECT my_id
      ,position('B' IN string_agg(event_type, '')) - 1 events_before_B
FROM (SELECT * from events order by my_id, tstamp) w
GROUP BY my_id
ORDER BY my_id`

Answer (score 1):

Do a self `LEFT JOIN`, with `GROUP BY`:

```
select e1.my_id, count(e2.my_id)
from events e1
    left join (select my_id, min(tstamp) as b_tstamp from events
               where event_type = 'B'
               group by my_id) e2
    ON e1.my_id = e2.my_id AND e1.tstamp < e2.b_tstamp
group by e1.my_id
```

Alternatively, `NOT EXISTS` version:

```
select my_id, count(*)
from events e1
where not exists (select 1 from events e2
                  where e2.my_id = e1.my_id
                    and e2.event_type = 'B'
                    and e2.tstamp < e1.tstamp)
group by my_id
```